# Simple select statement of SQLite takes 15 sec to fetch 17 records

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

Query :

```
select Name, id, Status, position,AId, Type from Building where Status != 0 and type = 0 order by Position
```

This query takes only one 1ms on SQLite browser on PC but same query takes around 15 sec to fetch only 17 records on android device.

I have used following index

```
create index B_type_position on building(type,position ASC)
```

and explain query shows that it has been used by optimizer still taking too much time to fetch records.

The time is calculated based on printing timestamps before and after `db.rawQuery(SQL,null);` statement.

Comment: With that few records your query shouldn't be that slow, but you should also add the Status column to your index.

Comment: Ahh, you have only 17 records.  This should fly no matter what indices you have.   Are you sure you are measuring time correctly?  Can you run 10 queries in a loop and see if it takes more than 3 minutes to run them?  Is there anything else going on your device? Are you on actual device or in the emulator?

Comment: I found the problem.
Due to singleton pattern complex query called from background thread takes too much time to execute and so that this simple query need to wait till that query completes its execution.
so I solved this problem by creating septate object of dbHelper for read operation and using singleton object for write operation.
I don’t know whether is it good practice or not but it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

How many records you have

You are filtering on type and status,  whereas your index is on type and position, so your index is on partially efficient the engine still has to do a lot of table scans.  Also after you filtered you data you are sorting by position for which you don't have an index.  Type,position doesn't help much in here either

Comment: I found the problem.
Due to singleton pattern complex query called from background thread takes too much time to execute and so that this simple query need to wait till that query completes its execution.
so I solved this problem by creating septate object of dbHelper for read operation and using singleton object for write operation.
I don’t know whether is it good practice or not but it solved my problem